# How to use query.filter and .filter_by in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sql, django, sqlalchemy

With Django it is possible to find models using the filter method with keyword-arguments like so:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(serialNo_gt=10)
```

giving all models with a serial number greater than 10.

Is it possibly to use a similar query language with sql-alchemy? I know that one can write something like `MyModel.seriealNO < 10`, but with that the code that uses this construct need to import `MyModel` and I want to create the keywords/query parameters externally without importing `MyModel` (for a facade-pattern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the concept of `"<attributename>_<operatorname>=<value>"` is not built in to SQLAlchemy's Query, however the effect is very easy to reproduce.   Here's a quick example done by the author of Flask: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/sqlalchemy-django-query/blob/master/sqlalchemy_django_query.py